# Cannot Click Into Text Field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am having trouble with one of my forms automatically creating a get request when I click to enter text inside of a text field. Once the get request is sent, I am unable to enter any text. I have searched quite a bit and not found any similar questions/issues. Does anyone know what may be going on here?

_new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit "Create Category", id: :create_category %>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<h1>Award Categories</h1>
<div id="categories">
    <% if @categories %>
        <% @categories.each do |c| %>
            <div><h2><%= link_to c.name, category_path(c) %></h2>
      </div>
      </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="addCategory" data-url="<%= new_category_path %>">Add new category</button>

<div id="newCategory"></div>
```

new.js.erb

```
$("#addCategory").html('<%= j render "categories/new" %>');
$("#new_category").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#category_name').val();
    var params = $(this).serialize();
    if ( name === ""){
        $('#name .help-block').remove();
        $('#name').prepend(`<div class="help-block">Please enter a name.</div>`);
    }else {

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/categories',
          data: params
        }).done(function(data) {
            var newCategory = new Category(data);
            var categoryHtml = newCategory.formatDisplay();
            $("#newCategory").remove();
            $('#categories').append(categoryHtml);
        });
    };
});

function Category(category) {
    this.name = category.name
    this.url = '/categories/' + category.id
}

Category.prototype.formatDisplay = function() {
    var categoryHtml = `<div><h2><a href="${this.url}">${this.name}</a></h2></div>`
    return categoryHtml;
};
```

categories.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#addCategory').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: $(this).data("url")
    }).done(function() {
    });
  });
});
```

get from terminal

```
Started GET "/categories/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-12 12:59:13 -0600
Processing by CategoriesController#new as */*
  Rendering categories/new.js.erb
  Rendered categories/_new.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered categories/new.js.erb (8.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 38ms (Views: 32.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

categories_controller#new

```
def new
    @category = Category.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

The issue happens after I click on "Add a new category" on the index page. Once that happens, the _new.html.erb form pops up, I click inside the text field, and a get request is fired immediately once I click in that field, not allowing me to type any text. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this to happen? Please let me know if there are any other pieces of code that would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show us the compiled html too?

Comment: I would need to read  your `controller#new` action

Answer (score 0):

on click your button will trigger a synchronous get request. It is default behaviour for links and buttons

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="addCategory" data-url="<%= new_category_path %>">Add new category</button>
```

to avoid having a synchronous `get` request performed on `click`, you will need `event.preventDefault();`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#addCategory').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       //... etc
```

you probably forgot this, if you do `event.preventDafault()` you will be able to get to you `$.ajax()` and create an `asyncronous` get request

you can also set a breakpoint to test this in your `categories.js`

Comment: Hi Fabrizio, thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, when I add the `event.preventDefault();` the get request is still firing when I click inside the text field.

Comment: I set a breakpoint, but I am relatively new at this so unsure as to what I would test once setting the breakpoint :/

Comment: I set a debugger after `event.preventDefault()` and hit it inside of the console

Comment: @Chris focus on how the http request is being triggered